# After Resampling Dataframe into Bins I need some key statistics

Tags: python, pandas

What my data frame looks like originally:

| order_id | canceled_at_local | accepted_at_local | Delta |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-21 18:21:58 | 2021-09-21 18:13:45 | 0 days 00:08:13 |  |
| 2 | 2021-08-15 12:03:00 | 2021-08-15 12:00:58 | 0 days 00:02:02 |  |
| 3 | 2021-07-12 15:48:14 | 2021-07-12 15:40:26 | 0 days 00:07:48 |  |
| 4 | 2021-08-11 20:52:59 | 2021-08-11 20:52:44 | 0 days 00:00:15 |  |
| 5 | 2021-07-09 22:34:34 | 2021-07-09 22:25:54 | 0 days 00:08:40 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Explanation of Dataframe:

`order_id` = unique order_id

`canceled_at_local` = the timestamp where customer canceled their order

`accepted_at_local` = the timestamp where the restaurant accepts their order

`Delta` = `canceled_at_local` - `accepted_at_local`

**After Resampling**

I dropped `canceled_at_local` and `accepted_at_local` so I only have my Delta column and my order_id's.

```
prod = df.resample('5S', on='Delta').count()
```

**Results after resampling:**

| Delta | order_id_counts |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 days 00:00:01 | 656 |  |  |  |
| 0 days 00:00:06 | 1348 |  |  |  |
| 0 days 00:00:11 | 3874 |  |  |  |
| 0 days 00:00:16 | 3586 |  |  |  |
| 0 days 00:00:21 | 2916 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

**Desired output**

Is there a way to find the Average weighted cancellations at a certain percentile?
I know I can use `prod.describe()` but I'm pretty sure the below is wrong since my `order_id_counts` is already COUNT aggregate.

| order_id_counts | Delta |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| count | 17198.0 |  |  |  |
| mean | 5.457727642749157 |  |  |  |
| std | 72.74624213714112 |  |  |  |
| min | 0.0 |  |  |  |
| 25% | 0.0 |  |  |  |
| 50% | 0.0 |  |  |  |
| 75% | 0.0 |  |  |  |
| max | 3874.0 |  |  |  |

Comment: I think you'll have to convert the Delta column to something interpretable by Pandas, e.g. seconds or minutes. Then describe() should work fine for percentile calculation.

Comment: HI @Bitswazsky your answer was correct! Thanks so much! I'd like to give you the credits if you don't mind but I'm not sure how.

Comment: It's okay. Glad it helped.